# Limit proof verification

Tags: limits, proof-verification, limits-without-lhopital

Question:

Prove that:

$\underset{x\rightarrow11^{-}}{\lim}\sqrt{x-2}=3$]

Answer:

Basically need to prove that : 
$\forall\varepsilon>0\,\,\exists\delta>0\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\quad-\delta<x-11<0\rightarrow\left|\sqrt{x-2}-3\right|<\varepsilon$

Perpwork:
Let $\varepsilon>0$
  be given.
$$\begin{array}{cc}
 & \left|\sqrt{x-2}-3\right|<\varepsilon\\
\iff & -\varepsilon<\sqrt{x-2}-3<\varepsilon\\
\iff & 3-\varepsilon<\sqrt{x-2}<3+\varepsilon\\
\iff & \left(3-\varepsilon\right)^{2}<|x-2|<\left(3+\varepsilon\right)^{2}\\
\\
\end{array}$$

Given that  $ \forall\varepsilon>0\quad\left(3-\varepsilon\right)^{2}\geq0$

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 & \left(3-\varepsilon\right)^{2}<|x-2|<\left(3+\varepsilon\right)^{2}\\
\rightarrow & \left(3-\varepsilon\right)^{2}<x-2<\left(3+\varepsilon\right)^{2}\\
\iff & \left(3-\varepsilon\right)^{2}+2<x<\left(3+\varepsilon\right)^{2}+2\\
\iff & \left(3-\varepsilon\right)^{2}-9<x-11<\left(3+\varepsilon\right)^{2}-9
\end{array}$$

Set $\delta<9-\left(3-\varepsilon\right)^{2}$

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
 & -\delta<x-11<0\\
\iff & \left(3-\varepsilon\right)^{2}-9<x-11 & \rightarrow & \left(3-\varepsilon\right)^{2}<|x-2|<\left(3+\varepsilon\right)^{2}\\
 &  & \rightarrow & -\varepsilon<\sqrt{x-2}-3<\varepsilon\\
 &  & \rightarrow & \left|\sqrt{x-2}-3\right|<\varepsilon
\end{array}$$
Q.E.D

Is this a legit proof ?

Comment: Thanks alex for your reply.  I used the rule that every real number squared is non negative the line before. Is it something that doesn't counts there?

Comment: Apologies, in your case it is. What I mean that for example if $0.1 <|x-2|<7$ then it doesn't follow that $0.1<x-2<7$ as $x-2$ can be negative

Comment: It opens up into two options the other one isn't in the real set ...